# JavaFx Communicating between controllers

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to send data from one controller to another and I decide to inherit the scene class with one of my controller so when I create the second scene I can pass it through an overloaded constructor that was extended.

Is it correct for a controller class to inherit Scene class?

Otherwise please suggest a more efficient way to communicate between controllers.

Comment: Can you explain that what actually are you trying do by establishing communication between controllers ?

Comment: How would inheritance help? Inheritance is a relationship defined at the class level. It's not going to help you communicate between two different instances of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Controller class should be separated from gui class. In mvc pattern there are three layers: model, controller and view.

View - gui class that extends Scene or other ui component.

Controller - listener class that catches events made by user

Model - holds data of program. Like username,password

You can also create separate classes to perform operations(add,subtract) of data in model

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry I'm new to javafx I didn't know about model only VC. I really appreciate:)